Regional high availability for Synapse dedicated SQL pool
We have provisioned a Synapse dedicated SQL pool for our business. We need to make sure that the service is highly available within the region. This means we cannot have the data be moved to another region but need to make sure that the DWH is available for querying.
I had a look at this question but it talks more about regional failure and disaster recovery.
What we are looking for is automatic recovery from a data center failure.
Infact most of the articles on google talk of DR rather than high availability.
I understand that storage can be made highly available using ZRS tier. But I was unable to find any official documentation that talks about the HA of the compute itself.
If someone can provide the official documentation for the SLA for dedicated SQL pool and how high availability is managed for it, it would be appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/backuprestore/restore-sql-pool

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/creating-a-custom-disaster-recovery-plan-for-your-synapse/ba-p/3746072
Can you please check if the above links will help you?

Thanks, even though the article does mention that there is high availability of Synapse, the SLA  https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/docs/view/Service-Level-Agreements-SLA-for-Online-Services?lang=1 still reflects 99.9% and only talks about the integration runtimes and not the Synapse dedicated SQL pool. Also the restart just talks of the SQL pool engine and not the dedicated sql pool storage zone redundancy.
